# Using one onchange event for multiple dropdow list which are listed among each other

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created a dynamic dropdown list and the first `<select name="club" id="club">` dropdown list will show the results of the mysql query below.
The second `<select name="player" id="player">` will be filled by the result of the query which is used in the ajax.php based on the id of the selection in the first

I will use this principal to select a player from a club.
For the selection of one club and player this is working fine, but how can I extend this small piece of code to use this for selecting for example 10 players.

So in this case I have created 10 select boxes among each other which I would prefer to use this small piece of code instead of copying this code 10 times.

```
$strQueryClubs = "SELECT ec.id, ec.name 
                        FROM club ec, season ss 
                       WHERE ec.season_id = ss.id
                         AND ss.status = 1 /* Active season*/
                    ORDER BY ec.name asc";

$resultQueryClubs   = mysql_query ($strQueryClubs);
$numQueryClubs      = mysql_numrows ($resultQueryClubs);

$arrQueryClubs  = $objDB->fetch_array($strQueryClubs);


<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#club').on('change',function(){
            var clubID = $(this).val();
            if(clubID){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'ajax.php',
                    data:'id='+clubID,
                    success:function(html){
                        $('#player').html(html);
                    }
                }); 
            }else{
                $('#player').html('<option value="">First select a club</option>');
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- language: lang-html -->
<select name="club" id="club">
            <option value="" disabled="disabled">Select club</option>
                <?php
                if ($numQueryClubs > 0)
                {
                    for ($i=0;$i<$numQueryClubs;$i++)
                    {
                        echo "<option value=".$arrQueryClubs[$i]['id'].">".$arrQueryClubs[$i]['name']."</option>";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<option value="">Club is not available</option>';
                }
                ?>
        </select>
        <select name="player" id="player">
            <option value="" disabled="disabled">Select player</option>
        </select>

<select name="club" id="club">
            <option value="" disabled="disabled">Select club</option>
                <?php
                if ($numQueryClubs > 0)
                {
                    for ($i=0;$i<$numQueryClubs;$i++)
                    {
                        echo "<option value=".$arrQueryClubs[$i]['id'].">".$arrQueryClubs[$i]['name']."</option>";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<option value="">Club is not available</option>';
                }
                ?>
        </select>
        <select name="player" id="player">
            <option value="" disabled="disabled">Select player</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: You will want to listen for a class, not an id. Then you probably want to send the name and value of the input so your php knows what to do.

Answer (score 0):

As Rasclatt mention in comment,listen event for **class** not **id**

As your requeriment of selecting 11 players, don't use 11 dropdowns.

I will suggest use multiple select by `multiple` property in select or any other plugins to avoid select perticular player twice.

Otherwise you need to refresh follwing dropdown to remove previously selected player